# How to create content type programatically

Tags: entities, nodes

how to create content type programatically and attach field api fields to it? hook_node_info() will not work for me since i want to create my node type and its instance in a single method (for testing purposes), so kindly suggest a solution other than hook_node_info().
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a node type, call [node_type_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_type_save/7). Have a look at the [documentation of the Fields API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/group/field/7) for information on how to attach fields to the node type.