# Drupal 6 - How to programatically create a content type

Tags: nodes

I am creating a module to display a dashboard that shows various stats. One section will be for adding announcements. My thought is that the best way to do this would be to create a custom content type and then pull in the latest announcements from the announcement content type submissions.

My question is how can I create that content type programatically with the proper fields? Where can I go to add those announcements once the type is created? And how can I pull the latest announcements to display on the page?

I'm new to Drupal, so I'm struggling at the moment to learn the proper way to do things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create content type programatically](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/how-to-create-content-type-programatically?rq=1). That answer is for Drupal 7, but the same function is available in Drupal 6. There is also this question: [How do I programmatically create a new content type?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15407/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-new-content-type?rq=1)

Comment: @AdamBalsam The first link you posted doesn't give much information other than a link to the documentation. I'm looking for some examples that will fit my situation. The second one doesn't even have a correct answer, rather a suggestion to use a third party module to solve the issue (not what I want to do).

Comment: For examples you can look at core itself and also the _Examples for developers_ project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module to export out the content type and the fields associated with it. Once you have done this you will have a .tar or .zip file of the export code in a functional module.

From here you are able to move that directory into your sites/all/modules directory and have a fully functional module.

Do remember to remove your content type and fields, before installing the module on your site. The new module will recreate them for you.